# image quality is not good in all device

Tags: android, bitmap, server, base64, android-volley

I'm trying to upload an image to server in my Android application by converting it to a base64 string. In this case when I try to upload an image the quality of my image is largely reduced and is very much blurred. Can you please help me overcome this issue.

whan i change o2.inSampleSize=10 it works well in motorola,samsung,lenovo but not work for all devices.  please suggest me why is this happning..

```
public Bitmap decodeFile(File f, int sampling) {
    try {
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
                new FileInputStream(f.getAbsolutePath()), null, o2);

        o2.inSampleSize = sampling;      //sampling=10
        o2.inTempStorage = new byte[48 * 1024];

        o2.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
                new FileInputStream(f.getAbsolutePath()), null, o2);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
        bitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, f.getAbsolutePath());
        //img = ConvertBitmapToString(bitmap);

        return bitmap;

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

converting bitmap to base64

```
  ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

  image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP,100,byteArrayOutputStream);

  String encodeImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(),Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: `//sampling=10` is bad. You should use only 1,2,4,8,16 etc. (multiplications by 2)

Answer (score 2):

Use Glide to Prepare your image : `.asBitmap().toBytes().into()`

then upload it.
For more info Check this link :https://github.com/bumptech/glide#glide

Or this Link: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1192

Answer (score 1):

Do not convert it, upload file with retrofit,okhttp.
Make a interface for url where acquires POST request

```
public interface FileUploadService {  
@Multipart
@POST("upload")
Call<ResponseBody> upload(
    @Part("description") RequestBody description,
    @Part MultipartBody.Part file
);}
```

then make a RequesBody var that holds your file and MultiPartBody var to hold file names too

```
 RequestBody requestFile =
        RequestBody.create(
                     MediaType.parse(getContentResolver().getType(fileUri)),
                     file
         );MultipartBody.Part body =
        MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("picture", file.getName(), requestFile);
```

and the description of file:

```
RequestBody description =
        RequestBody.create(
                okhttp3.MultipartBody.FORM, "someFile");
```

then upload it via retrofit

```
Call<ResponseBody> call = service.upload(description, body);
call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call,
                           Response<ResponseBody> response) {
        Log.v("Upload", "success");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e("Upload error:", t.getMessage());
    }
});
```

for more information check [this](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server).